# UICollectionView loads images in the wrong order for a second

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView with custom cell that has some labels and an UIImageView, the data is downloaded from some Json and then I populate my cells, the problem is that when I scroll up again the image of some cell changes for a second into a wrong one (of another product) and then they reset to the correct one again. I'm using Lazy Loading for the UIImageView with the following library https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView has anyone had my same issue?
The code where I populate the cell is the followin:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [self performSelector:@selector(test) withObject:nil];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


    // Configure the cell
    FidelityProducts *item = _feedItems[indexPath.row];
    //load the image

    urlImg = [NSURL URLWithString:item.urlImg];
    cell.img.showActivityIndicator = true;
    cell.img.imageURL = urlImg;
    cell.titolo.text = item.nomeProdotto;
    cell.codice.text = item.codice;
    cell.prezzo.text = item.prezzo;

    UIView *bottomBorder = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, cell.frame.size.height - 1, cell.frame.size.width, 1)];
    bottomBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:bottomBorder];


    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `prepareForReuse` in your custom `UICollectionView` class and there set the image to `nil`. This should solve your problem:

```
- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];

    [self.img setImage:nil];
}
```

Not really sure how this lazy loading UIImageView works, maybe you need to also set the `imageUrl` to `nil`.

Hope it works for you. Good luck!

Comment: Tried but with no luck :( the method gets called correctly but the bug still happens, thanks for the help anyways! :)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since you ask, but I was facing a similar issue, without LazyLoad.

I set the tag of my cell with some identifier, that later I used on the dispatch queue to make sure I was loading the same cell.

Here is my code:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cvCell";


UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:237.0/255.0 green:238.0/255.0 blue:238.0/255.0 alpha:1];
for (UIView *vw in [cell subviews])
{
    [vw removeFromSuperview];
}


    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] imageURL]];
    NSInteger evID =[[self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ID].integerValue ;
    [cell setTag:evID];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{


        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
        UIImageView *imagem = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake([GRAPHICS SCREEN_X], [GRAPHICS SCREEN_Y],106,106 )];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
//here is the trick for loading the right image

            if (cell.tag==evID) {


            [imagem setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
            [imagem setImage:image];
            [cell addSubview:imagem];
            [cell setNeedsLayout];
            }

        });
    });



return cell;
}
```

Hope this helps others